# Autodesk Viewer GPS Functionality

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I was wondering if there is any support for GPS functionality for the autodesk 3D viewers, or if there is going to be support in the future.

I am asking this question because we would like to use GPS specific data in the viewer gathered from drone inspections 3D models. To give an example you could render a Google Map with the correct coordinates provided from the 3D drone scan.

Think a little like this:

[image: Google Maps with rendered model]

Comment: Not available and I don't think there are plans to add this kind of feature in the near future unfortunately

Comment: @Philippe That's unfortunate! Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: If you are using Revit documents for example you can attach geolocalization coordinates to components in the model as metadata/properties which can then be accessed in the Forge model and used by your application. Another workaround would be to store any needed data in a custom database mapped to a specific model that is then used in the Forge application to position the model. I do not see major problems doing so.

Comment: @Philippe Thanks that would be an option! We will see if it fits into our workflow.

Comment: Since V6 there's the [GeolocationExtension](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/Extensions/GeolocationExtension/) that looks like it does what you need.

Comment: @LewyBlue thank you so much for your answer! This could indeed be a solution.